# Overly strong IV?

Tags: regression, statistical-power, instrumental-variables, f-statistic

I heard that a too high F-statistic in the first stage of an instrumental variable regression can also be bad because it means that the IV is highly correlated with other endogenous variables. Does anybody know of a more formal treatment of this?

Comment: can you give a reference?

Comment: I am asking for a reference! This was a comment, I don't know where it's from